# Condition for $z$ to $|P(z)|\lt 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I want to investigate when it's true that $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{(P(z))^n} = \frac{1}{1-P(z)}$ where $P(z)$ is a complex polynomial. I think the condition is $|P(z)|\lt 1$ but I don't know how to get condition for $z$ from this. Maybe triangle inequality is useful here.

Comment: The condition $|P(z)|<1$ is both sufficient and necessary. Translating $|P(z)|<1$ into something more explicit about $z$ is not doable in general.

Comment: @Reveillark So there is no general formula for that?

Comment: I would say no. If you could solve $|P(z)|<1$ in a nice fashion, you could probably adapt the method to solving $|P(z)|<r$ for every positive $r$, and this would give a method of solving $P(z)=0$, at which point alarm bells would go off. This is obviously a very hand-wavy heuristic, but still.

Comment: @Reveillark Okay, thanks. So I'll keep the question open.